# Google Pay with Authorize.net: Failed Transaction. Error 153 There was an error processing the payment data. Unable to decrypt data

Tags: authorize.net, google-pay

Google Pay with Authorize.net:

Failed Transaction.

Error Code: 153

Error Message: There was an error processing the payment data. Unable to decrypt data.

Comment: Are you able to include sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Two causes of this error that I experienced:

1. The token Google Pay returns to the front end must then be base64 encoded before it is submitted to Authorize.net by the back end. In Javascript that's `const base64Token = btoa(token)`.
2. When switching from the sandbox Authorize.net gateway to the production Authorize.net gateway, you need to switch both the front end and the back end. Switching only one but not the other can cause this error.